# upgrade v. 2.8.5 to latest version of wordpress

Tags: upgrade, wordpress-version

Is it possible to upgrade WordPress version 2.8.5 to 3.9.2? I am trying to upgrade but the WordPress give me the link to download the latest version of WordPress. If it is possible, how am I going to upgrade my version 2.8.5 to 3.9.5?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Visit `http://your-domain.com/wp-admin/update-core.php` and look for the heading "An updated version of WordPress is available."

Below that there should a button for "Update Now". You can update by hitting that button.

If it's not there then you will have to manually update your website. For that instructions are here.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update

Comment: Thanks but I tried to click the button 'Update Now', and there's a provided link. It says you have to download the newest version of WordPress and it gives me an empty dashboard.
Okay so for now, I need to do the manual update because the button Upgrade didn't upgrade the version I want

Comment: Yes, in that case you will have to update manually. It's not big a deal. You just need to be little careful, that's all. And also keep a backup before manually updating because it's very easy to make mistakes in this process. :)

Comment: if you don't mind, do you have tutorial in wordpress? about adding categories that have a link and redirect to other page. I am a newbie here in wordpress and I don't know how to use anything in wordpress hehe

Comment: sorry, I do not know any such tutorial.